# triple slash comments not working in namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I would like to know if there is a way to get the /// documentation comments to work within a namespace block. They work fine in every other situation, is there a reason they are disabled inside namespaces or is it a bug? I am working in Visual Studio 2013 coding in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: Working fine here. VS 2013 w/ resharper

Comment: This works for me as well, can you edit the question to show a screen print or an example of the comment you're attempting to make?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug; it's unsupported by design. *(As for the "why" behind the decision, I wouldn't know.)*

From the notes on [Compiler Warning (level 2) CS1587](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3x6ez1z(v=vs.90).aspx):

> XML comment is not placed on a valid language element
>
> Recommended tags for documentation comments are not allowed on all language elements. For example, a tag is not allowed on a namespace. For more information on XML comments, see [Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=vs.90).aspx).

There's even an example in that doc of exactly what you're trying to do.

*(The doc says VS2008 at the top, but I verified I'm getting the same warning in VS2013.)*

Comment: I think OP is questioning straight up triple slash comments inside the namespace block, not XML tags.  At least I don't see any mention of compiler warnings in the question as it currently exists.